# Checking existence of a remote file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, fopen

I'm trying to find a best solution to save from **performance, memory usage** etc. for checking if a file exist on different domain or not. In my case, the file is an **XML** and the size can be between **10KB up to 10MB**.

Which of these would be the best to use? If you have a better approach, I'll be happy to use it instead.

Thanks

**CURL**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/hello.xml");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
// $retcode > 400 -> not found, $retcode = 200, found.
curl_close($ch);
```

**FOPEN**

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/hello.xml";

if (@fopen($url, "r")) {
   echo "File Exists";
} else {
   echo "Can't Connect to File";
}
```

Comment: curl is faster. See [this previous question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636678/what-are-the-important-differences-between-using-fopenurl-and-curl-in-php)

Comment: Incase of XML file Why not `simplexml_load_file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'HEAD'
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = fopen('http://example.com/submit.php', 'rb', false, $context);
```

[Example taken (but shortened) from the manual](http://php.net/context.http)

Then use [`stream_get_meta_data()`](http://php.net/stream-get-meta-data) to fetch the response headers, something like

```
$meta = stream_get_meta_data($result);
var_dump($meta['wrapper_data']);
```

Comment: As **Dow** says above comment, cURL is faster. There is a test run in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636678/what-are-the-important-differences-between-using-fopenurl-and-curl-in-php) too.

Comment: Even if I could (slightly) reproduce the behaviour I wouldn't name some uncommented numbers "a test". In my opinion the streams are much easier to handle. "Performance" is not everything